# How to properly use macros for functions?

Tags: c

I have an array with numbers. Three sorts of number (`float`, `double`, etc) and when I search for a specific number, it should return / show the location in the array of that number.

So the idea is that I could place numbers like -3, 1.25 in the array without defining specifically the array type, since I need to receive any kind of number.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define finder(find_num, array,type,format)\
void find_num(type array[], type ,int size)\
{\
    int location = 0, i;\
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)\
    {\
        location++;\
        if (array[i] == num)\
            break;\
    }\
    if (location != arry[0]\
        printf("Location of the number is at %d place\n", result);\
    else\
        printf("Location of number not found\n");\
}

finder(funcfind, int array[], int %d\t, int %d\t);
finder(funcfind, int array[] ,double %f, int %d\t)

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 5,6,7,88,12,3,20 }, result = 0, num = 0, size = 0;
    size = sizeof(array);
    scanf("%d", &num);
    funcfind(array, num, size);
}
```

I need to use macros for this exercise, but i am getting stuck on the `finder` function and the `funcfind` where most of my errors come from.

**UPDATE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define finder(find_num, array ,type ,format)\
void find_num(type array[], type num,int size)\
{\
    int location = 0, i;\
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)\
    {\
        location++;\
        if (array[i] == num)\
            break;\
    }\
    if (location != array[0])\
        printf("Location of the number is at %d place\n", location);\
    else\
        printf("Location of number not found\n");\
}

finder(funcfind, array, double, int %d\t);
finder(funcfind, array, int, int %d\t);
finder(funcfind, array, float, int %d\t);

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 5,6,7,-3,1.5,3,20 }, num = 0, size = 0;
    size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    scanf("%d", &num);
    funcfind(array, num, size);
}
```

Its working but some numbers like -3 and 1.5 are not working

Comment: There are not `sizeof(array)` elements in the array. There are `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` elements. So you iterate over more array elements than exist which is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: You should take a look at your code after preprocessing. If you are using gcc you can simply pass the `-E` flag.

Comment: when you have a doubt ask for to see the result after the pre processing, for instance with _gcc_ do _gcc -E ..._

Comment: Please check that your two uses of `finder`are what you intend them to be. Then explain what that is, especially the part where what looks like meant to be a prototype for the function (but fails, because of the body) has a different type than the implementaion.

Comment: Please show the preproscessed code, I cannot imagine how it can even compile. Therefore I doubt that the code you show and the code you use are sufficiently similar.

Comment: @Yunnosch that is the code i am trying to run, as you suggested, its not working, because its incomplete, as you can see, those are attempts.

Comment: What is the compiler's output? There are a lot of errors in this code. `main` should return something, and you're missing a semicolon and some other stuff. Try fixing all compiler warnings before attempting to make progress.

Comment: Take a real hard look at the arguments you are passing to the macro - does `int %d\t` make sense as a *type*?  Does it make sense as a *format*?  Can you pass a type *by itself* as a function argument?  Then think about the name `funcfind` - can you create two functions with the same name that take different argument types?

Comment: For VS add the `/Fi` option followed by the name for the preprocessed file, e.g. `/FiNameForPreprocessedFile` to your compile string. Get out of VScode, open the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" and compile your code with `cl /nologo /W3 /Ofast /FiNameForPreprocessedFile /Tc yoursource.c`

Comment: Do you know using `-E`? if not please ask about it. If yes please do so and look at the output. It cannot ever be what you intend and it should make mulitple fixable mistakes obvious.

Comment: See `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`? He is on windows using VS.

Comment: What do you intend `finder(funcfind, int array[], int %d\t, int %d\t);` to expand to? I guess you want it to become a prototype for the function implementation below.

Comment: What do you intend `finder(funcfind, int array[] ,double %f, int %d\t)` to be expanded to? I guess it is meant to be the implementation of the prototype above.

Comment: Why did you not tag c-preprocessor?

Comment: Correction, the `/P` option is needed along with `/Fi`, so it will be `cl /nologo /W3 /Ox /P /FiNameOfPreprocessedFile /FeNameOfExex /Tc yoursource.c`

Comment: get your code right first of all, then start abstracting it. what the heck is your `find_num` function supposed to do? print the index of `num` if found in `array` ? if yes, it doesnt do that. besides, even if it was correct, it is overly complicated: `void find_num(type array[], type num, size_t size){
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      if(num == array[i]) {
         printf("found at pos %zu\n", i);
         return;
      }
   }
   printf("not found");
}`

only when this compiles and you verified it works, start generalizing.

Comment: ah, I should mention: it won't work like you intend because of the `location != array[0]` check. i highly assume you actually want `location > 0`. Again, dont write overly complex solutions if there are simple ones. you dont need `location` to solve your problem, so get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

If I pass the pre processing (gcc -E) the result is :

```
void funcfind(int %d\t int array[][], int %d\t ,int size){ int location = 0, i; for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { location++; if (int array[][i] == num) break; } if (location != arry[0] printf("Location of the number is at %d place\n", result); else printf("Location of number not found\n");};
void funcfind(double %f int array[][], double %f ,int size){ int location = 0, i; for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { location++; if (int array[][i] == num) break; } if (location != arry[0] printf("Location of the number is at %d place\n", result); else printf("Location of number not found\n");}
```

*type* is `int %d\t` so the first parameter is wrong, why that `int %d` rather than `int v` for instance ?

because it is difficult to guess what you want I let you continue to fixe the problems

anyway in the macro 
- `void find_num(type array[], type ,int size)` is strange and perhaps must be `void find_num(type array[], type num,int size)` and the calls `void find_num(type array[], type ,int size);` and `finder(funcfind, array ,double, int %d\t)` 
- `if (location != arry[0]\` must be `if (location != array[0])\`

that gives :

```
void funcfind(int array[], int num ,int size){ int location = 0, i; for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { location++; if (array[i] == num) break; } if (location != array[0]) printf("Location of the number is at %d place\n", result); else printf("Location of number not found\n");};
void funcfind(double array[], double num ,int size){ int location = 0, i; for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { location++; if (array[i] == num) break; } if (location != array[0]) printf("Location of the number is at %d place\n", result); else printf("Location of number not found\n");}
```

if I indent the first function :

```
void funcfind(int array[], int num ,int size){
  int location = 0, i;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    location++;
    if (array[i] == num)
      break;
  }
  if (location != array[0])
    printf("Location of the number is at %d place\n", result); 
  else
    printf("Location of number not found\n");
};
```

so there are some few error like *result* unknown etc, but I think you can solve easily

Comment: This is really helpful. It is however not an answer. Please add some of the problems visible in the prepro-code, that will make it an answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes, I start to do :)

Comment: Risky, but recommendable. Consider temporarily deleting the answer. People who feel like me, but are more trigger-happy, might otherwise downvote.

Comment: @bruno now most of the errors are gone, i now have only those 2 errors:

`Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2664 'void funcfind(double [],double,int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int [7]' to 'double []'`

and

`Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2447 '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)`

Answer (score -1):

Your macro definition isn't defined correctly.  You also use it to define two functions with the same which isn't allowed.

This:

```
finder(funcfind, int array[], int %d\t, int %d\t);
```

Expands to:

```
void funcfind(int %d\t int array[][], int %d\t, int size)
...
```

And this:

```
finder(funcfind, int array[] ,double %f, int %d\t)
```

To this:

```
void funcfind(double %f int array[][], double %f, int size)
...
```

Which is invalid syntax.

Define the macro as follows to create a separate function for each type, then you can use a `_Generic` to choose which function to call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define finder_impl(type)\
void find_ ## type(type array[], type num, int size)\
{\
    int location = 0, i;\
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)\
    {\
        location++;\
        if (array[i] == num)\
            break;\
    }\
    if (location < size)\
        printf("Location of the number is at %d place\n", location);\
    else\
        printf("Location of number not found\n");\
}

finder_impl(int)
finder_impl(double)

#define findfunc(array, num, type) \
    _Generic ((num), \
              int: find_int,\
              double: find_double\
             )(array, num, type)

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 5,6,7,88,12,3,20 }, num;
    int size;
    size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    scanf("%d", &num);
    findfunc(array, num, size);

    double array2[] = { 2.5, 4, 3.25, 7 }, num2;
    size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    scanf("%lf", &num2);
    findfunc(array2, num2, size);
}
```

Comment: I bet you a dinner that defining two functions is not what OP intends. I pay up if you visit me.

Comment: two function with the same ... ?